# How to add background image to a div in angular 8?

Tags: angular, typescript, angular8, ng-style

I want to add background image to the `div` with class `row1`. I have tried using `style.background` and `style.background-image`.

.html

```html
<div class="row1"  [style.background-image]="'url('imgUrl') ' " >
```

.ts

```js
imgUrl="assets/images/userImg.png"
```

Answer (score 1):

You `imgUrl` is a variable, but you are using its name.

Try

```
<div class="row1" [style.background-image]="'url(\'' + imgUrl + '\')'" >
```

Comment: by using this I am getting multiple images

Answer (score 0):

Use this:

```
<div class="row1" [ngStyle]="{ 'background': 'url(' + imgUrl + ')' }"></div>
```

or

```
<div class="row1" [style.background]="'url(' + imgUrl + ')'"></div>
```

Comment: by using this I am getting multiple images

Comment: @naman Try also add this - 'background-repeat': 'no-repeat'